# On default, is libevent level-triggered or edge-triggered?

Tags: c, network-programming, libevent

On default, is libevent level-triggered or edge-triggered? I don't find any documentation about this.

Comment: When I did a quick search for `is "libevent" level or edge triggered` the first result I got was [this](https://libevent-users.monkey.narkive.com/NXIFZQ2K/support-for-edge-triggered-behaviour) which states that it defaults to level-triggered events. But do note, it's 15 years old at this time. Though even if edge-triggering have been added since then, level-triggering is likely still the default.

Comment: libevent provides backends that don't even support an edge-triggered mode.  If you want to be sure to get one that does support edge-triggered then you have to express that to libevent explicitly.